# How can I change state of an Article with the corresponding Button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building my first React demo.  I'd like to learn how to write a function and/or useEffect that will display an article based on which button was clicked.  I have 4 buttons always visible and I'd like to have 1 article visible depending on which one is selected.  Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Here's the setup I have so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import './main.css'
import mainData from './mainData'
import Button from './menuButtons'
import Article from './contentCard'

function Main() {
    const [menuProps] = React.useState(mainData.menu)
    const [buttons, setButtonActive] = React.useState(mainData.buttons)
    const [articles, setArticle] = React.useState(mainData.articles[0])

    function setActive(key) {
        setButtonActive(prevActive => {
            return prevActive.map((button) => {
                return button.key === key ? {...button, active: true} : {...button, active: false}
            })
        })
    }

    const buttonElements = buttons.map((buttonProps) => (
        <Button 
            key={buttonProps.key}
            label={buttonProps.label}
            active={buttonProps.active}
            setactive={() => setActive(buttonProps.key)}
        />
    ))

      
    return (
        <main className='content-container flex'>
            <section className='menu flex'>
                <img src={menuProps.img} alt='Travelogue splash images'/>
                <h1>{menuProps.title}</h1>
                <p>{menuProps.description}</p>
            
                <div className='menu-buttons flex'>
                    {buttonElements}
                </div>
            </section>

            <Article
                key={articles.key}
                style={{backgroundImage: `url(${articles.img})`}}
                title={articles.title}
                description={articles.description}
            />
       </main>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Comment: Do you have a CodeSandbox example? We don't know what Article is right now.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Not quite sure how to run a snippet of this one component.  I'm pulling all the props for the menu, buttons, and articles from a local data file.  I'm just stuck on what to write to associate the buttons to the right article to update which article array is the active state

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share the function structure that worked for me in this scenario...

[For a little more clarification, I'm using a separate data JS file that contains the content, mainData as shown above, that gets mapped in the main.js file for both the buttons and articles.  Button keys are set in the data file with a value the same as an index]

```
function setButtonActive(key) {
    setActive(prevActive => {
        return prevActive.map((button, index) => {
            if (key === index) {
                setArticle(mainData.articles[index])
            }
            return button.key === key ? 
                {...button, active: true} : {...button, active: false}
        })
    })
}
```

The site is now live so everyone can see the finished result of what I was aiming for:
https://willfranck.github.io/react-demo-travel-site/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With your state, how are you determining which button is active?

```
 const [buttons, setButtonActive] = React.useState(mainData.buttons)  
 const [articles, setArticle] = React.useState(mainData.articles[0])
```

Here it looks you are mixing two concepts - setting elements as buttons and setting a button as active. I'm not sure what your `mainData.buttons` is, but unless you are planning on changing the buttons based on user actions, you don't need to set them in state. You've imported them, you can use them.

You should use `useState` for setting a button as active - how you decide to do that is ultimately up to you. The same is true of articles. How are buttons and articles related? From there, you can determine how to structure your state.

Comment: Roger that.  Thanks!  It's been an interesting learning process and I appreciate the tip